# Delete an item from firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase and wondering how can I make so that I can delete an item from my users database, and the item only gets deleted after the user inserts a specific code let's say 1234

Json example for an order

```
 {
      "address_id" : "-Kn6eXyJ9XhglrVgA3eo",
      "item_qty" : 1,
      "payment_id" : "CREDIT",
      "product_id" : "item1",
      "product_image" : "chicken_maharaja",
      "product_name" : "New Chicken Maharaja",
      "product_price" : 130,
      "status" : "Queued",
      "user_id" : "D6yOQ1ZwWwYL69z80xJ0rLTASwG2",
      "user_name" : "Bogdan Incrosnatu"
    }
```

The controller that shows the users current order

```
.controller('lastOrdersCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,fireBaseData,sharedUtils) {

    $rootScope.extras = true;
    sharedUtils.showLoading();

    //Check if user already logged in
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        $scope.user_info = user;

        fireBaseData.refOrder()
          .orderByChild('user_id')
          .startAt($scope.user_info.uid).endAt($scope.user_info.uid)
          .once('value', function (snapshot) {
            $scope.orders = snapshot.val();
            $scope.$apply();
          });
          sharedUtils.hideLoading();
      }
    });



})
```

LastOrder.html

```
<ion-view style="" class=" " id="page10" title="Orders">
    <ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">


      <ion-list ng-repeat="item in orders" ng-hide="user.hide">

        <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left" >

          <img  ng-src="{{'img/fk/'+ item.product_image +'.jpg'}}" >

          <a class="badge badge-balanced" style="position: absolute;right:0;" >{{item.status}}</a>
          <h4> {{item.product_name}} </h4> 

          <button ng-click="removeRecord(user)">Delete</button>



        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>


    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your using angularjs means. why can't you go  for using angular fire, it's a library provided by firebase. just add the cdn and inject the firebase module in

```
var app=angular.module("appname",["firebase"]) like this
```

your main angular js module and then in your controller. inject 
$firebaseArray(Service provided by firebase).

```
app.controller("controllername",function($scope,$firebaseArray){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    $scope.user_info = user;

   var fb_query= firebase.database().ref("Pass your tree name here")
      .orderByChild('user_id')
      .startAt($scope.user_info.uid).endAt($scope.user_info.uid);
```

then pass it to the firebasearray

```
$scope.orders=$firebaseArray(fb_query);
$scope.orders.$loaded().then(function(){
    //you will get data here.
 var Rec= $scope.orders.$getRecord(//Pass the Id here)
 //you have to pass record id i.e($id) from the firebase object, to delete a data from firebase tree.
 //for ex
 var Rec= $scope.orders.$getRecord(1);
 if(Rec){
   scope.orders.$remove(rec).then(function(){
   //Success 
}).catch(function(){
   //error..
})
 }
    })  
  }
});
})
```

// or do something like this.

```
var object={}
object["/Your tree name"+ pass ur Id]=null;
firebase.database().ref().update(object).then(function(){
  console.log("Successfully deleted")
})
```

Comment: I already have the first part of the code, but I don't exactly understand where I should add the second part , the one with the firebase array

Comment: I don't understand exactly what and if I should add anything where the comments are

Comment: Tell me exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: Hello! are you there?